# Role of the ApplicationManager in YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

[image]

I am reading a book and the above picture is described as the `ResourceManager` in YARN.

They state:

1. `Admin and Client Service` is responsible "for client interactions such such as a job request submission, start, restart, and so on"
2. "`ApplicationMaster Launcher` launches the container for the ApplicationMaster on job submission from client."

Then they contradict what they said above with the below statement:

> The ApplicationManager is responsible for accepting the client’s job submission requests, negotiating the containers to execute the applications specific to the ApplicationMaster, and providing the services to restart the ApplicationMaster on failure.

**Question:**

I thought the role of the of the Admin and Client Service was to accept the client job submission and not the ApplicationManager role? So essentially does the ApplicationManager get the job from the Admin and Client service and uses the ApplicationMaster Launcher to actually launch the ApplicationMaster with the resources specified in the job submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct application manager get the job from admin and Client service. 
ApplicationsManager is responsible for maintaining a collection of submitted applications or jobs. After application submission, it first validates the application’s specifications and rejects any application that requests unsatisfiable resources for it.Once the application manager is satisfied then application master launcher, launches application master.
The application master is responsible for negotiating resources from Resource Manager and working with node manager to execute and monitor the container and their resource consumption. one important thing is that each job have its own application master. Which is not applicable for application manager.

You can visit this link http://javacrunch.in/Yarn.jsp if you want to see the communication flow within Yarn.

Hope this solve your query.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubts. I have one more clarification. When the `ApplicationManager` retrieves the job from the `Admin and Client Service`, does the job contain the resources that is required to launch an ApplicationMaster? Like how does the `ResourceManager` know how much resources the ApplicationMaster needs? Or does the `ResourceManager` just have a set amount of resources to launch any `ApplicationMaster` and then after the `ApplicationMaster` is launched it will ask the `ResourceManager` for resources specific to the application?

Comment: Yes, ApplicationManager retrieves the job from the Admin and Client Service, that job contain the information about the resources that is required to launch an ApplicationMaster, in most cases the resource requirement for application master are standard. But The critical component for any job is the identification of resources that are required for launching containers on the datanode which will do the  actual job and that are computed by application master.

Comment: Ah ok now that makes sense. So the resource requirement for the ApplicationMaster is standard (so you can think of it as a POJO that gets launched in the container) but how does the ApplicationMaster decide how much resources it needs to run the actual job on the datanode? Is that also specified in the job that is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

You can find more details about ApplicationsManager in [YARN](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) official documentation page.

[image]

The idea is to have a global **ResourceManager** (RM) and per-application **ApplicationMaster** (AM)

The per-application **ApplicationMaster** is, in effect, a framework specific library and is tasked with negotiating resources from the ResourceManager and working with the NodeManager(s) to execute and monitor the tasks.

The **ResourceManager** is the ultimate authority that arbitrates resources among all the applications in the system.

The **ResourceManager** has two main components: **Scheduler** and **ApplicationsManager**.

The **Scheduler** is responsible for allocating resources to the various running applications subject to familiar constraints of capacities, queues etc. The Scheduler does not performs monitoring or tracking of status for the application.

The **ApplicationsManager** is responsible for

1. Accepting job-submissions
2. Negotiating the first container for executing the application specific ApplicationMaster
3. And provides the service for restarting the ApplicationMaster container on failure.

The per-application **ApplicationMaster** has the responsibility of negotiating appropriate resource containers from the Scheduler, tracking their status and monitoring for progress.

Regarding your query

> When the ApplicationManager retrieves the job from the Admin and Client Service, does the job contain the resources that is required to launch an ApplicationMaster? Like how does the ResourceManager know how much resources the ApplicationMaster needs?

*ResoruceManager ( ApplicationsManager+Scheduler)* in collaboration with ApplicationsMaster make sure that resources are allocated for the client request and they perform the roles as explained above.